# How do I downgrade Firefox developer version to stable version on Ubuntu+1?

Tags: installation, firefox, downgrade, beta

I want to downgrade to Firefox *X stable* from *Y beta* due to add-on incompatibilities.

For example from Firefox *11 beta* to Firefox *10 stable*.

How can I go to stable channel?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of Ubuntu uninstall Firefox 11 beta and download Firefox 10 with the Internet (from any stable site), but if you are using an older version of Ubuntu you use menu to return application to previous version (using Synaptic, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the beta channel PPA,you could just remove the PPA from "Software Sources".

1. Go to dash
2. Type "software sources"
3. Scroll down till you find the firefox beta ppa.
4. Remove the check, and firefox will be downgraded at the next upgrade.