# changing a ppa from dev to stable safely

Tags: firefox, ppa

ubuntu comes with firefox (stable) built-in. I wanted to try Aurora, so I added ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora to the source list and upgraded this way :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

now let us suppose that I want to go back to the stable version of firefox, what would be the safest way to do so ?

thank you.

Edit :

As pointed out by @vasa1, I am not talking specifically about firefox, but about the concept of going back to a lesser version in general.
I have google-chrome installed so I guess, Ubuntu will one end up browserless.

---

Problem solved using @IgnitE's solution.

Comment: A similar, but not identical, question [was closed as too localized](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103510/how-do-i-downgrade-firefox-developer-version-to-stable-version-on-ubuntu1).

Comment: Actually my question is not really specific to firefox, but to the concept of going back to a lesser version safely.

Comment: But do let us know how you managed to get back to Firefox stable!

Comment: The problem was solved using @IgnitE's solution. the ppa-purge downgraded firefox automatically. but thank you for your detailed info on www-browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ppa-purge` to remove a ppa. Just do:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

Description from man page:

> ppa-purge - disables a PPA and reverts to official packages.
>   This script provides a bash shell script capable of automatically downgrading all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions.

(You can install `ppa-purge` by `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm restricting my answer to the Firefox aspect of the question.

While a plain installation of Ubuntu comes with Firefox pre-installed, OP seems to have replaced that with Aurora (a development version of Firefox) by means of a PPA.

It isn't clear now whether OP has some other browser installed as well. This point may be significant because Ubuntu needs to have a browser present at all times: see [Why does removing Firefox install another browser?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11934/25656) and [Can I uninstall & replace Firefox with another browser of my choice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/51136/25656).

In view of the requirement for a `www-browser`, OP maybe better off first checking out the software installed on the system using `dpkg --get-selections`. If there's an acceptable alternative to Firefox present, purging the Aurora PPA shouldn't pose a problem. The purge step can then be followed by a simple `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

However, if Aurora is the only browser present, I'm not sure that purging the PPA first will be successful. OP would need to study the output from `apt-get` at this point.

Apologies for posting this as an answer in case it's deemed to be irrelevant.

Comment: I have google-chrome installed so i guess it would not be a problem.